# If $r+r’\leq d(a,a’)$ then $B(a,r)\cap B(a’,r’)= \emptyset$.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I have to prove this assertion :

Suppose that $r+r’\leq d(a,a’)$

Show that $B(a,r)\cap B(a’,r’)= \emptyset$.
What I have to prove is that if I have $p \in B(a,r)\cap B(a’,r’)  $ then $p=0$.

If $p \in B(a,r)\cap B(a’,r’)$ then : 
$$d(a,p)<r $$
$$d(a’,p)<r’$$
Then : 
$$0\leq d(a,p)+d(a’,p)\leq r+r’ \leq d(a,a’) \leq d(a,p)+d(p,a’)$$
Know I’m stuck, can I Say that $d(a,a’)=d(a,p)+d(a’,p)$ according to the last inequality ? If yes, I don’t know I to prove that $p=0$...

Comment: Being empty does *not* mean the only element is $0$. It means the *number* of elements id $0$. Does $B(a,r)$ denote the *open* ball centred at $a$?

Comment: Oh yes, absolutly ! Thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "What I have to proove is that if I have $p \in B(a,r)\cap B(a’,r’)  $ then $p=0$."

That is a wrong route and can only be marked as an effort to prove the *weaker* statement : $$B(a,r)\cap B(a’,r’)=\varnothing\text{ or } B(a,r)\cap B(a’,r’)=\{0\}$$

It must be shown that the assumption $p \in B(a,r)\cap B(a’,r’)$ leads to a contradiction.

If $p \in B(a,r)\cap B(a’,r’)$ then  $$d(a,a')\leq d(a,p)+d(p,a')<r+r'$$ contradicting that $r+r'\leq d(a,a')$.

Answer (score 2):

I assume the balls are open, otherwise the statement is not true.

Let $p\in B(a,r)$, i.e. $d(a,p)\lt r$. Then the triangle inequality states that

$$d(a,p)+d(p,a')\ge d(a,a')\ge r+r'$$

Hence

$$d(p,a')\ge (r-d(a,p))+r'>r'$$

Hence $p\notin B(a',r')$.

Therefore, $B(a,r)\cap B(a',r')=\emptyset$.

---

Note that it's absolutely not true that you have to show that *if $p \in B(a,r)\cap B(a’,r’)$ then $p=0$*. If $p=0$ were in $B(a,r)\cap B(a’,r’)$, then obviously the intersection would not be empty.

Comment: Yes that is true, the empty set is not the set which contains $0$... Thank you Jean Claude !